# Action only dispatched when called using arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been fiddling about and reading docs, but I can't figure out why this *doesn't* work.

I have a component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {
    pieceDropped,
} from "./BoardActions";

const Foo = (props) => (
    <Bar
        onDrop={(move) => props.onDrop(move)}
    />
);

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    onDrop: pieceDropped,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ...
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo)
```

An action defined elsewhere:

```
export const pieceDropped = ({sourceSquare, targetSquare}) => ({
    type: PIECE_DROPPED,
    payload: {sourceSquare, targetSquare}
});
```

And a reducer that deals with that dispatcher. This currently works fine.

What I don't understand is why in the component, if I replace the arrow function with a cleaner assignment like:

```
const Foo = (props) => (
    <Bar
        onDrop={props.onDrop}
    />
);
```

My action is no longer dispatched.

I've read the redux docs, and learned about object destructuring in function contexts to make sure it wasn't something wrong with the dispatcher, but I can't figure out why this way doesn't work.

Bar's `onDrop` prop has the following signature:

```
  onDrop?: (obj: {sourceSquare: string, targetSquare: string, piece: string}) => void,
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code?

Comment: @Miller I'm not really sure how to set up a react-redux jsfiddle, never used it before

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/ Give it a try! I believe the problem is inside your pseudo component `Bar` and how it's executing the callback. With the code running is easier to identify what's wrong

Comment: could you provide the some codes about <Bar />? especially about the onDrop.

Comment: So `Bar` is actually from the Chessboard.jsx library, here's the source code for it [here](https://github.com/willb335/chessboardjsx/blob/master/src/Chessboard/index.js)